# Should I hardcode a value for e.g. $NAMESERVERHOSTADDRESS$?

Tags: linux, nagios

I would like to use the Nagios plugin `check_dns`, so when I look at the command definition to it

```
define command {
  command_name    check_dns
  command_line    $USER1$/check_dns -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -s $NAMESERVERHOSTADDRESS$ -a $EXPECTEDIPADDRESS$
}
```

I see that `$NAMESERVERHOSTADDRESS$` is not a [standard macro](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/macrolist.html), so I am not sure what to put as `command_line` and what to put in the service definition.

```
define service {
  use                     generic-service
  name                    check_dns
  host_name               ns.example.com
  service_description     Checks DNS
  check_command           check_dns
  contact_groups          linux-admins
}
```

The goal is to let the Nagios monitor host ask `ns.example.com` to lookup `test.example.com` to see if the resolves to the expected IP.

**Question**

Should I replace/hardcode `$NAMESERVERHOSTADDRESS$` in the command definition, with the value I want?

Or should the value of `$NAMESERVERHOSTADDRESS$` be defined in the service definition? And if so, how?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're using `check_dns` for? Are you testing that your DNS server works, or are you testing that a certain host name resolves properly?

Comment: Good point. Post have been updated.

Comment: Do you define your host's `address` as an IP in the `define host`, or FQDNs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have such a definition in my server. You can change the definition to use `$ARGn$` like:

```
define command {
  command_name    check_dns
  command_line    $USER1$/check_dns -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -s $ARG1$ -a $ARG2$
}
```

Then, you can use it the service definition like:

```
define service {
  use                     generic-service
  name                    check_dns
  host_name               ns.example.com
  service_description     Checks DNS
  check_command           check_dns!name_server!expected_address
  contact_groups          linux-admins
}
```

You need to replace `name_server` and `expected_address` with the actual values.